# Cycles isn't appearing in render engine drop down list

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I just upgraded to 2.75 and there isn't an option for cycles render in the engine drop down.  How do I access cycles render in the new environment?  It only list, blender render and blender game.

Comment: It should be there.. Is it in the list of addons? Try reverting to factory settings

Comment: What OS are you using? Where did you get blender from?

Answer (score 3):

First thing to check is in the Addons tab in the User Preferences:

> User Preferences > Addons > Render: Cycles Render Engine.

My best first guess is that the box for this option is unchecked.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just needed to check the cycles render engine check box.